# 3rd party component not recognized in javafx scene builder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am using the javafx ribbons components that is implemented by custom library from this post: https://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/ribbon-for-java-using-javafx/

Everything is fine but the only issue is that I can't open the FXML files using the scene builder. Every time I open a file it gives class not found exception. I tried to add the fxml as a custom component to the scene builder but it gave the same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

Create an empty project, add to it the classes and the corresponding FXML files containing the elements you want to be included in the scene builder, build your project to generate a jar file, open the scene builder, select import "JAR/FXML file" and import the jars you have generated. The elements will be added to the custom section in the scene builder